# Regex with non-capturing group using stringr in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to use non-capturing groups with the `str_extract` function from the `stringr` package. Here is an example:

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "foo"
str_extract(txt,"(?:f)(o+)")
```

This returns

```
"foo"
```

while i expect it to return only

```
"oo"
```

like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244553/3750030

How do i use non-capturing groups in R to remove the content of the groups from the returned value while using it for matching?

Comment: Try `str_extract(txt,"(?<=f)(o+)")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are using regex `(?:f)(o+)` this won't **Capture** but it will match it for sure.

What capturing means is *storing in memory* for back-referencing, so that it can be used for repeated match in same string or replacing *captured* string.

> like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244553/3750030

You misunderstood that answer. **Non-Capturing** groups doesn't means **Non-Matching.** It's captured in `$1` ( group 1 ) because there is no group prior to it.

If you wish to **Only** match suppose *B* followed by *A* then you should use `positive lookbehind` like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=f)(o+)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=f)` This will look for `f` to be present behind the following token but **won't match**.
- `(o+)` This will match and **capture as group** (here in $1)if previous condition is true.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ8nZ3/1)**

Comment: FYI: capturing groups are inaccessible with `str_extract`. Use `str_match` instead. In this case, `(?<=f)o+` is enough.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks for the detailed explanation!